# Does a file served through Django HttpResponse enter memory or stream from disk?

Tags: python, django, apache

Say you have two options for serving a large file in Django, you can:

1. Open your media directory to the public, and serve the file directly through Apache, Nginx, etc.
2. You can process the file with Django before sending it, then send the file with something like this:

```
from django.core.files.base import File
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotModified

def send_the_file(request, filename):

    # Do something ...

    # Send the file ...
    with File(open(filename, 'rb')) as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f.chunks())
    return response
```

Will Django stream the large file from disk like Apache would? Or will I waste threads and space reading the whole file into memory?

Comment: I think if you want django to stream you should use ```StreamingHttpResponse```

Comment: I was thinking that too, but then I read this in the docs: `StreamingHttpResponse should only be used in situations where it is absolutely required that the whole content isn’t iterated before transferring the data to the client.`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse

Comment: `FileResponse` is a subclass of `StreamingHttpResponse`. That might be what I need. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general... yes.

If you use `StreamingHttpResponse`, then it might not be read into memory all at once, because you can garbage collect the file chunk before sending the next chunk. The whole file will still go through memory though.

If you want to avoid reading a file into memory (thereby avoiding devoting a Django worker to the request), then you should use Django to pass instructions to your server's API for sending files from disk. That API depends entirely on your server.